# Texture blurry on retina and crisp on regular

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, scaling, retina-display

I've got some bizarre behavior running my nascent game under the iPad Retina simulator vs. the iPad non-Retina simulator (both iOS 7.1).

The grass is blurry on retina, but crisp on non-retina:

[image]

[image]

What might be the cause of this? The texture is being drawn using `glDrawElements` after having done the `glActiveTexture()` and `glBindTexture()` calls, and having `glMapBuffer()`d the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, using the same `.png` file in both instances.

Comment: Does the retina display on iOS devices draw at its native resolution? In OS X, they do upscaling for retina MacBook Pros. The system renders at something like 1900x1200 and then is upscaled to 2880x1800, you have to poke around a lot to get the window system to render at the native non-scaled resolution on OS X. If you took a mangnifying glass and looked at the individual pixels you would see blurring (interpolation). This could be the same problem, if this is infact an issue with the display technology and not something completely unrelated.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Oh interesting. I can't quite tell but it seems blurry on my retina iPhone as well. But I don't understand why the simulator running on the same screen would show it as crisp if retina is off, and blurry otherwise ..

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: If I run it without `enableRetinaDisplay:YES` on the iPhone, it is indeed crisper.. unless I move around a bit and then it goes back to blurry. (prob related to game logic) . but it is crisper at first